# PyTorch Input and hidden tensors not on the same device

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch

I'm creating a simple LSTM model to predict some sales data. I am trying to train it on a GPU, but there seems to be a problem with casting the hidden state tensor to cuda.
I get the following error:
`RuntimeError: Input and hidden tensors are not at the same device, found input tensor at cuda:0 and hidden tensor at cpu`.
How can I train the model on a GPU? I cast the training data, initial hidden states, and the model to cuda, yet I still get the error.

Here's my code:

```
# Convert train_norm from an array to a tensor
train_norm = torch.FloatTensor(train_norm).view(-1).cuda()

# define a window size
window_size = 12

# Define function to create seq/label tuples

def input_data(seq, ws): # ws is window size
    out = []
    L = len(seq)

    for i in range(L-ws):
        window = seq[i:i+ws]
        label = seq[i+ws:i+ws+1]

        out.append((window, label))

    return out

# Apply the input_data function to the train_norm
train_data = input_data(train_norm, window_size)

class LSTM(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_size=1, hidden_size=100, output_size=1):
        super().__init__()
        self.hidden_size = hidden_size
        
        # Add an LSTM layer:
        self.lstm = nn.LSTM(input_size, hidden_size)

        # Add a fully connected linear layer:
        self.linear = nn.Linear(hidden_size, output_size)

        # Initialize h0 and c0:
        self.hidden = (torch.zeros(1, 1, hidden_size).cuda(), torch.zeros(1, 1, hidden_size).cuda())

    def forward(self, seq):
        lstm_out, self.hidden = self.lstm(seq.view(len(seq), 1, -1), self.hidden)
        pred = self.linear(lstm_out.view(len(seq), -1))

        return pred[-1] # get only the last value

model = LSTM().cuda()

criterion = nn.MSELoss()
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.001)

epochs = 200

import time
start_time = time.time()

for epoch in range(epochs):
    
    # Extract the sequence and label from the training data
    for seq, y_train in train_data:

        # Reset the parameters and hidden states
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        hidden = (torch.zeros(1, 1, model.hidden_size),
                  torch.zeros(1, 1, model.hidden_size))
        model.hidden = hidden

        # Predict the values
        y_pred = model(seq)

        # Calculate loss and perform backpropagation
        loss = criterion(y_pred, y_train)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()

    print(f'epoch: {epoch+1:2} loss: {loss.item():10.8f}')

print(f'Training took {time.time() - start_time:.0f} seconds')
```

Comment: I would try to put the input parameter seq to device: seq.to(device), where device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all you are initializing `hidden` when there is absolutely no point to do it. If `hidden` isn't passed to `LSTM` layer it will be `zero` **by default**, please [see documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.LSTM.html#torch.nn.LSTM). This gives us the following model:

```
class LSTM(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_size=1, hidden_size=100, output_size=1):
        super().__init__()
        self.hidden_size = hidden_size

        # Add an LSTM layer:
        self.lstm = nn.LSTM(input_size, hidden_size)

        # Add a fully connected linear layer:
        self.linear = nn.Linear(hidden_size, output_size)

    def forward(self, seq):
        lstm_out, _ = self.lstm(seq.view(len(seq), 1, -1))
        return self.linear(lstm_out.view(len(seq), -1))
```

Your `pred[-1]` is probably wrong as well as you are only returning the last element of `batch` from linear layer...

Also your training should be this (see `hidden` removed and added `cuda` to `seq` and `y_train`):

```
for epoch in range(epochs):
    
    # Extract the sequence and label from the training data
    for seq, y_train in train_data:

        # Reset the parameters and hidden states
        optimizer.zero_grad()

        # Predict the values
        # Add cuda to sequence
        y_pred = model(seq.cuda())

        # Calculate loss and perform backpropagation
        loss = criterion(y_pred, y_train.cuda())
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()

    print(f'epoch: {epoch+1:2} loss: {loss.item():10.8f}')

print(f'Training took {time.time() - start_time:.0f} seconds')
```

This alleviates problems with `cuda` (it's not a solution to hardcode it everywhere you possibly can...) and makes your code more readable.